# MySQL Query with condition that is based on several rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with measurements of stars. 
Each row (i.e. a measurement) contains the star's ID and its Period.

Lets say for example:

```
Star_ID    Period
1          4.1
1          3.6
2          4.1
2          4.1
2          8.7
3          2.5
4          1.3
4          1.3
```

I want to write a query that returns the Star_ID's only of the stars which have more then one measurement with the same period. In our example, it should return {2,4}.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option which just does a `GROUP BY` only on the `Star_ID` column:

```
SELECT Star_ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Star_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT Period) >= 1
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can use group by and having

```
select Start_ID 
from my_table 
group by star_ID, Period 
having count(*) > 1
```

You can obtain the desired value 
grouping the rows by `start_id` and `Period`  and for this getting the count of the number of rows ..
 then you can filter the result using having and checking fo  count(*) > 1..

Comment: Please explain in brief so that the PO can learn something new.

Comment: And if the condition on the period is more complicated? i.e. instead of equal period - periods that satisfies P1 - P2 < x ?

Comment: @Tomer  ... sql give you specific function for the question like your  .. these function are the base for aggregation evaluation function . for P1 - P2 < x is another question and you should post a specific question with proper sample